# What is "strobe"?

Tags: cpu

For advancing the

address input of the RAM, we provide the

signal “strobe”.

Can anyone explain this in a bit more detail?
Thanks.

Comment: Quite of-topic, it is more about digital electronics than computer science and it lacks details about the type of RAM, etc...

Comment: well, to be honest, I do not think that this is the wrong place for my question!

Comment: Indeed, this seems off-topic here, as it is about electrical engineering.

Comment: for new users it seems to be not obvious where exactly to post their question. Because a few of them (including me) do not know all the different places where they can ask their question. For me, it is kind of annoying to get answers like "this is off-topic here" a several times now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the strobe is a hardware concept, it is sometimes directly referred to in software. A strobe is generally a voltage line in the computer, sometimes on the CPU or another chip on the motherboard, for example. The voltage of a strobe line will need to go high or low at certain times for certain things to happen. How's that for vague?

On an older computer like an Apple ][, you could directly read the strobe signal of the keyboard controller from a particular memory location. This would tell you whether the user had pressed a key or not and allow you to either handle it or continue on with other processing.